# Angular Material Progress Spinner with Image icons - (mat-spinner)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I Implemented mat-spinner in my project, but it only has few configurable changes like Color, mode of spinning. I want to include Image Icon which is the Logo of a brand/Company inside the spinner, how can i achieve it ?

Below is the Stackblitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/lmgppgejqxdv

It has mode and color change but how do i include any image to fit inside the progress spinner ?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the background layer of the spinner using:

```
.mat-progress-spinner svg {
  background: red;
}
```

Note however that the svg is subject to transforms, so the background may end up being rotated as well.

Comment: How to stop background Image being rotated ? and also fit the background image exactly inside the spinner boundary, right now the background red is going off the spinner boundary and it is spinning as well